# Why are these topics appearing?

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a basic question. I've "installed" all the bits for a Turtlebot3 on my ubuntu running in vmware.

I have run roscore.

I have explicitly run a single script which creates a single new topic, cmd_vel.

But when I list `rostopic list` is see a long list of topics (see below).

It is clear that those topic come from the Turtlebot3 installed code. But my question is what ended up "invoking it"? As the only thing I've run are roscore and my little script, lots of other code must be in play to declare those topics.

Can someone please clarify?

Here's the list:

```
/camera/depth/camera_info
/camera/depth/image_raw
/camera/depth/points
/camera/parameter_descriptions
/camera/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/camera_info
/camera/rgb/image_raw
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/clock
/cmd_vel
/joint_states
/mobile_base/commands/motor_power
/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry
/mobile_base/commands/velocity
/mobile_base/events/bumper
/mobile_base/events/cliff
/mobile_base/sensors/imu_data
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267317/why-are-these-topics-appearing?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Possibly you are running RViz or something similar. If you have subscribers, topics will appear. You can check with `rostopic info`.

For example `rostopic info /camera/depth/camera_info` will give you publishers and subscribers if there exists any.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2017-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-07-25**:
I guessed something like that, but where or what or how did RViz get run? If it's installed (rosdep) at all does it always run?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2017-07-25**:
Of course, no. We can get a better idea if you can post the output of `rostopic info /camera/depth/camera_info` for example.